# How to stop Libreoffice (German) from replacing three dots "..." by the three-dots-character "…"?

Tags: libreoffice, autocorrect, german

I updated not too long ago. In the previous installed version I had turned this off. In the version installed now I can't find the optionbox. ):

Version: 5.3.0.3 (x64) BS-Version: Windows 6.1; UI-Render: Standard; Layout-Engine: neu; Gebietsschema: de-DE (de_DE); Calc: single

I'm 100% sure in the version installed before it was possible to turn off this replacement distinctly, so complete turning off of autocorrection or completion or whatever it is called was not necessary.

I don't want to turn off the whole autcorrection or completion or whatever! (Only this *totally superfluous three-dot-character*!)

(Edit) Turning off the option 'autocorrection during entry' ("AutoKorrektur -> Während der Eingabe") turns off the replacing. But I don't want to turn of everything.

Removing every instance, that is in every language version listed, of the replacement needles `.*...` and `...` from the autocorrection options ("AutoKorrektur -> AutoKorrektur-Optionen...") didn't help either. Program restart didn't change anything. For a test trying to remove something easier from only the German language versions like `:Bus vorne:` didn't have any effect either.
(Another 2 hours wasted.)

I would say: Definitly a bug. Someone report it on their website please.

Comment: Go [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=LibreOffice;bug_status=UNCONFIRMED;version=?) to report the bug.

Comment: Deleting `.*...` from the autocorrect options > Replace works in the English version. See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/67935/unwanted-ellipsis/ Looks like a bug in the German version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug when using Libreoffice with a document in German language or with the program's language set to German.

Answer (score 1):

#### In the version installed now I can't find the optionbox.

1. Go to "Menu" > "Tools" > "Options" > "Language Settings" > "English sentence checking"
2. In the "Punctuation" block uncheck "Ellipsis"
3. Click "OK"

   [image]

Note:

- The menu item names and dialog box entry names and text may be different in the German version of LibreOffice.

Comment: I have nearly the same entries in German language on the left, just missing one of your "Grammar checking (" entries. The according box for Ellipsis does exist, and is deselected like in your picture. This does not have any effect, sadly. Maybe there needs to be a "German sentence ch..."? I already did search on the website, but I didn't find anything that could fit. - Seems to be a bug in the interface currently in that there is no effect when running Libreoffice in German setting. Restarting before and after didn't help.

Comment: @John That's not good. The grammar checking ... entries I have a for Portuguese and Russian. I've no idea why I have those, or the Hungarian entry either. I may have installed extra language packs or dictionaries at some point but I don't remember choosing those languages (I don't use them).

Comment: @john I wonder if the [LanguageTool](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/languagetool) extension has a relevant setting? "LanguageTool is a style and grammar proofreading software for English, French, German, Polish, Dutch, Romanian, and a lot of other languages."

Answer (score 0):

I'm regularly updating via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to:

```
Version: 5.4.0.3 (x64)
Build-ID: 7556cbc6811c9d992f4064ab9287069087d7f62c
CPU-Threads: 8; Betriebssystem:Windows 6.19; UI-Render: GL; 
Gebietsschema: de-DE (de_DE); Calc: group
```

And here it is at the same menu position as [David Postill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) mentioned.
(Extras/Optionen/Spracheinstellungen/Englische Satzkontrolle/Dreifachpunkte)
[image]

Comment: And does the option box have any effect when selecting or unselecting it? In my version not.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Three dots are always replaced independent of the setting - if it is check marked or not. Thats definitely still a flaw.